# input bootstrap JavaScript and CSS in Django

Tags: html, django

I have my bootstrap files in the static folder in Django but I think Js is not imported because there are no javascript effects working

here is the code i used to import CSS and js :

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel='stylesheet' href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type="text/css">
  <script src ="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

everything is perfectly styled but no script works at all, is this the right way to get the JS files into my HTML doc?

Here is my app dir, Inside the static folder there are the bootstrap files 
and inside the templates folder there is the HTML file am editing

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some image of the tree source of your static folder, please? And, how do you import bootstrap, with npm?

Comment: Done in the edited part of the question

Comment: Have you configured your static files destination in settings file?

Comment: it allready configured like this :
STATIC_URL = '/static/'